# Linq query will change often- how can I change it without recompiling app?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

My application will be querying a database using Entity Framework.  The problem is that the database table structure changes fairly often (a few times a year).

Back in the SQL days, we would store SQL queries in Resource files (.resx) and when any database changes occurred, we could just edit the one resource file and not have to edit any code in the app, recompile, etc.

Are there any good ways to do this with Linq-to-SQL?

Comment: If the change were to remove a column, for instance, I don't see how you could do anything but fix code and recompile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq2SQL is innately code-based.  If your schema is going to change, then the code will need to change.

The only way I can see around this, and still get some of the benefits of linq, is to write everything as Stored Procedures, which you can than add as method to the linq DataContext.

Then, as long as the Name, input parameters and output columns remain the same, you can change what the SP is doing on the database and the code can stay the same.